# R: Could not get two graphs plot with the same starting X values

Tags: r, graph

I'm plotting density probabilities against predicted probabilities with poisson distribution in R, this is the code I used:

```
dens=density(data)
plot(dens$x,dens$y,type="l",xlab="Value",
     ylab="Count estimate",ylim=c(0,0.2),xlim=range(0:22),col=4,lwd=2)
lines(dpois(0:22,lambda=estimated_lambda), col=2,lwd=2)
```

And this is the result:

[image]

For some reason I couldn't get both lines to line up, even though both have the same x-axis range (as shown in the code above), it should work the same given that both values are discrete, and if I plot the dpois not using `lines` then the other line will not show up at all.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please make this reproducible by adding some `data`. Also, what does `summary(dens$x)` say? Have you tried to specify `x =0:22` in the call of `lines`? I think you'll get a wrong plot w/o it.

Comment: Right I actually figured this out right after, turns out using `density` is the wrong idea since I need something more closer to a histogram, switching that and changing some stuffs around solved it, ty though

Comment: Then please consider writing an answer yourself or deleting the question so people do not put any more effort into solving what is already solved.